# Prove that if $T,U: V \rightarrow V$ are linear operators on an inner product space, then $(TU)^* = U^*T^*$

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that if $T,U: V \rightarrow V$ are linear operators on an inner product space, then $(TU)^* = U^*T^*$

So, the $^*$ represents taking the conjugate and transpose. I've been tinkering around with this by writing $T$ and $U$ as some sort of matrix and work out the calculations but I keep getting lost. is there a standard way to show this? Thank you!